# Maximum simple path with budget on edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

This is a part of a self formulated question, and hence I have not been able to "Google" it and my own attempts have been futile till now.

You are given a graph **G(V,E)** each **Node** of **V** has a profit **wi**, each **Edge** of  **E** has a cost of **ci**. We are now given a budget **C**, what is required to be found is a single path such that the sum of costs is less than **C** where sum of **wi** is maximum.Path has the normal definition here that is a path will not contain repeating vertices (simple path).

It is obvious that Hamiltonian path is a special case of this(Setting cost = |N-1| and the cost of each edge=1), and hence this is an NP Hard problem, so I am looking for approximation solutions, and heuristics.

Mathematically

Given Graph **G(V,E)**

**ci >=0** for each edge **e**

**wi >=0** for each vertex **v**

find a simple path **P** such that

Sum **ci** over all edges **e** in **P** <=  **C**

Maximise **Sum wi** for all **v** in **P**

Comment: Why is the Hamiltonian path a special case? Your problem doesn't state that the path can only visit each vertex at most once.

Comment: I think you want to specify that ci >= 0, and the profit of a vertex goes to zero once you visit it or that you can only visit a vertex once.

Comment: @Patrick: For cost=0 for all edges, cost=1 for all vertices - if this problem has a solution of length |V|, then the there is a hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the Selective Travelling Salesman Problem, or Travelling Salesman with profits. Google Scholar should be able to give you some references. Metaheuristics such as genetic programming or tabu search are often used. If you want to solve the problem optimally, linear programming techniques would probably work (unfortunately, you don't state the size of the instances you're dealing with). If the length of the path is small (say 15 vertices), also [color-coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color-coding) might work.

Comment: The rough size I am looking at is about 50 Nodes, and a almost complete graph, but the cost function usually means that not more than  15 nodes will be there in the path

Answer (score 0):

One simple heuristic that cones to mind is a variation of stochastic [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) and [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search).

Define value function that is increasing in the weight and decreasing with the cost. For example:

```
value(u,v) = w(v) / [c(u,v) + epsilon]
(+ epsilon for the case of c(u,v) = 0)
```

Now, the idea is:

From a vertex `u`, proceed to vertex `v` with probability:

```
P(v|u) = value(u,v) / sum(u,x) [ for all feasible moves (u,x) ]
```

Repeat until you cannot continue.

This solution will give you one solution - quickly, but it is probably not near optimal. However - it is stochastic - you can always re-run it again and again, while you have time.

This will give you an **[anytime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anytime_algorithm)** algorithm for this problem, meaning - the more time you have - the better your solution is.

Some optimizations:

- You can try to learn macros to accelerate each search, which will result in more searches for each amount of time, and probably - better solutions.
- Usually, the first search is not stochastic, and is purely greedy, following the `max{value(u,v)}`